# How to do this effect? :S

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I'll be more then grateful if someone can give me some hints in achieving  this effect from here:
http://branditylab.com/#branditylab/home

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick look at the code in the console shows they are probably using [particlejs](https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js/)

edit:
So we get downvotes for answering bad questions now?

Comment: Maybe my question was stupid but I really appreciate your answer :D

Comment: Yea I disagree with you getting downvoted for answering the question. Have an upvote.

Comment: No problem, glad it helped you.  The StackOverflow community prefers specific questions about code-- not general/subjective questions, and not questions about "what library is this using."  You *might* get better reception for this sort of question at [ProgrammersExchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) -- no guarantees, but worth a shot next time.  Good luck!

Comment: @StephanGenyk -- thanks much! Sorry, didn't mean to be all sour grapes about it, but was kind of surprised by that one.